# Azure Functions and Swagger UI - How to display query string paramters in swagger UI?

Tags: swagger, azure-functions, swagger-ui, azure-http-trigger

I'm having the following Azure Function which is HTTP triggered. I have set up Swagger for my endpoints using this link [here](https://github.com/vitalybibikov/AzureExtensions.Swashbuckle). The following API expects a set of query string parameters, namely, *"name", "email", "phone"*, so it can do some search against the target object. At the moment the body of the function of course is not implemented and that won't matter for this question though.

My question: How can I have the query string parameters displayed in the swagger UI?

**The Function:**

```
[FunctionName(nameof(GetBookingCalendarsFunction))]
 public async Task<IActionResult> GetAllAsync(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "GET", Route = "bookings")] HttpRequest request,
        ILogger log)
    {
        log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

        return new OkObjectResult($"Name: {request.Query["name"]}, email: {request.Query["email"]}, phone: {request.Query["phone"]}");
    }
```

**The swagger UI for this function**

[image]

**Note:** I don't want to use route values instead of query string parameters, because, having those parameters are optional and the callers may not want to for example provide one of them.

For example, I've tried the following but it will fail with 404 if you remove any of the parameters as it takes them as part of the route (even though it will show them up in the Swagger)

```
  [FunctionName(nameof(GetBookingCalendarsFunction))]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetAllAsync(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "GET", Route = "bookings/name={name}&email={email}&phone={phone}")] HttpRequest request,
        string name, string email, string phone,
        ILogger log)
    {
        log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

        return new OkObjectResult($"Name: {request.Query["name"]}, email: {request.Query["email"]}, phone: {request.Query["phone"]}");
    }
```

I've been Googling around for hours now but couldn't find anything helpful so far. Appreciate your help.

Comment: You most likely need to decorate your function definition with some form of attribute from the SwashBuckle package that you're using.

Comment: Does `[FromQuery] HttpRequest request` work?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since you use package `AzureExtensions.Swashbuckle` to integrate Swagger in Azure function, we can use Attribute `QueryStringParameter` to configure query string according to your need. For more details, please refer to [here](https://github.com/vitalybibikov/AzureExtensions.Swashbuckle/blob/master/src/AzureFunctions.Extensions.Swashbuckle/AzureFunctions.Extensions.Swashbuckle/Attribute/QueryStringParamaterAttribute.cs)

For example

```
 [FunctionName("GetBookingCalendarsFunction")]
        [QueryStringParameter("name", "this is name", DataType = typeof(string), Required = false)]
        [QueryStringParameter("email", "this is email", DataType = typeof(string), Required = false)]
        [QueryStringParameter("phone", "this is phone", DataType = typeof(string), Required = false)]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> GetAllAsync(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", Route = "bookings")] HttpRequest req,
            ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

           

            return new OkObjectResult($"Name: {req.Query["name"]}, email: {req.Query["email"]}, phone: {req.Query["phone"]}");
        }
```

[image]